# How to Change KeyFrame Duration

Tags: java

I have a moving group of shapes that grows in size, and when it reaches a certain size I want the speed at which it moves (seconds) to increase, but I cannot figure out how to update the seconds variable for my KeyFrame. The seconds variable is a global variable that I initially set to 0.2 within my start method. I store the length of the group in an ArrayList so I would do something like

```
if(groupList.size() >= 3 && groupList.size() <= 8){
      seconds = 0.15;
}
if(groupList.size() >= 9 && groupList.size() <= 14){
      seconds = 0.09;
}
```

etc. This code above is in my start method. I have my KeyFrame in a method called move:

```
public void move(){
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(seconds), e -> {
            //bunch of if statements for game logic
    });
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
    timeline.play();}
```

So in my start method, I have it in this order:

```
gameStart();
move();
if(groupList.size() >= 3 && groupList.size() <= 8){
      seconds = 0.15;
      move();
}
if(groupList.size() >= 9 && groupList.size() <= 14){
      seconds = 0.09;
      move();
}
```

Comment: At the required point, replace the existing frame frame with a new one?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was under the impression that my code was doing that since I was creating a new timeline and keyframe within my move method. I was thinking that maybe I make the timeline a global variable, and the key frame, then instantiate the keyframe inside the method so instead of it being              
 KeyFrame frame = new Keyframe(//code) it would just be                           
 frame = new KeyFrame(//code)

Comment: Not an expert in JavaFX, but did you remove the previous `TimeLine`?

Comment: I have not, I'm obviously pretty new to JavaFX so no worries haha.

Comment: It may not work, but makes sense that you don't want the previous `TimeLine` playing along with the new one ;)

Comment: Yep it works! Thanks!!

Comment: Consider providing your own answer, it may help some one else ;)

Comment: Yup I edited my original post and shouted you out!

Comment: Post and actually answer, you can then self accept it and if any one else finds it useful, you get build some rep ;)

Comment: Ah yea I didn't think about that haha, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the if statements, I added timeline.stop() and timeline.getKeyFrames().clear() before the move method call and after changing the seconds variable and it worked! Shoutout to @MadProgrammer for the solution!

```
if(groupList.size() >= 3 && groupList.size() <= 8){
  seconds = 0.15;
  timeline.stop();
  timeline.getKeyFrames().clear();
  move();
}
if(groupList.size() >= 9 && groupList.size() <= 14){
  seconds = 0.09;
  timeline.stop();
  timeline.getKeyFrames().clear();
  move();
}
```